# ActiveRecord exception caught after being eaten

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I've got a GCP pubsub listener that does some work and then saves to ActiveRecord. I don't want to do that work if the DB connection is down, so I've added a pre-flight check. The pre-flight check checks the DB connection, and if it fails, eats the error and raises a `RuntimeError`. The DB is flighty though, and to account for the scenario where the pre-flight succeeds, but the DB connection dies while the work is being done, I have the caller rescuing `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError` and `PG::Error`, so we can log that the work was done, but the receipt couldn't be persisted. It's more important that this work not be duplicated than for the receipt to be persisted, so `RuntimeError` isn't caught, (causing a retry), but the DB errors are. It looks like this (snipping significantly):

```rb
# Service
def process
  begin
    WorkReceipt.do_work
  rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError, PG::Error
    Rails.logger.error("Work was done successfully, but not persisted")
  end
end
```

```rb
# Model
class WorkReceipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.do_work
    if !ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?
      Rails.logger.error("DB connection is inactive. Reconnecting...")
      begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
      rescue => e
        Rails.logger.error("Could not reestablish connection: #{e}")
        raise "Could not connect to database"
      end
    end

    # Lots of hard work

    self.create!(
      # Some args
    )
  end
end
```

Where things get weird is, while testing this, I brought down the DB and fired off 4 of these tasks. The first one handles correctly (`"Could not reestablish connection: server closed the connection unexpectedly"`), but then the other 3 get `"DB connection is inactive. Reconnecting..."` (good) followed by `"Work was done successfully, but not persisted"` (what?!). Even weirder, is that the work has logging and side-effects which I don't see happening. The pre-flight appears to correctly prevent the work from being done, but the database error is showing up in the outer `rescue`, preventing the retry and making me sad. There is no database access other than the `create` at the end.

What is going on here? Why does it seem like the database error is skipping past the inner `rescue` to be caught by the outer one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand how Ruby works, but changing `raise "Could not connect to database"` to `raise RuntimeError.new "Could not connect to database"` fixes the problem. I was under the impression that providing a message to `raise` caused it to emit a `RuntimeError` without needing to be explicit about it, but here we are.